How do spiders know where food is stored in their web?
I recently caught a new black widow after a previous one died during molting. I added it to the same enclosure I kept the previous one, without removing the old web. The new spider almost immediately after encountering the web, climbed into it and found a bug the old spider had captured and hung in its web for a later meal, and started eating.
Given how quickly the newly captured spider was able to locate food within the old web, I was wondering how spiders (black widows more specifically) keep track of where things are in their web. I assume at least part of it is memory based as the previous spider was much more confident in climbing around its own web, while the new one had to pause occasionally and search for web to climb on. However, given that black widows can produce pheromones for mating purposes which can be detected by sensory hairs, can distinguish between prey vibrations and vibratory courtship displays, and the fact that some males bring a food item to distract females when mating suggests that more than just memory could play a role in how widows are able to locate food they, or potentially another widow, have cached.
